# startactivityforresult from dialogpreference (non activity)

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a dialog preference with a button on it that I want to have open another activity. When that activity is complete, I want the dialog to update a textview (in the dialog) with the information that was gathered from the activity.

In other words:
Preference screen --> Dialog preference --> Dialog --> Button click event --> Activity

I used to have a normal activity call the activity (Activity --> Button click --> Activity) so I could use startactivityforresult, and then call my syncgui function from "onactivityresult". Sadly, the Dialog preference is not an activity, and therefore can only use startactivity (from context), not startactivityforresult (from activity).

Is there any other way I can tell my dialog that the activity it started is done and that it can update the textview? Here are the original functions

Old parent activity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == mSimModeBrowse) {
            Intent i = new Intent("com.shared.FileChooser");
            i.putExtra("com.shared.FileChooser.EXTRA_PATH", vsbPath);
            i.putExtra("com.shared.FileChooser.EXTRA_EXTENSIONS", vsbExtensions);
            startActivityForResult(i,0);
        }
    }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            final String file = data.getExtras().getString("com.shared.FileChooser.EXTRA_RESULT");
            mSimModePath.setText(file);
        }
    }
```

from filechooser (child activity):

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        File f = new File(path + "/" + files.get(position));
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_RESULT,f.getAbsolutePath());
        setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() 
    { 
        Intent i = new Intent("com.shared.FileChooser");
        i.putExtra("com.shared.FileChooser.EXTRA_PATH", vsbPath);
        i.putExtra("com.shared.FileChooser.EXTRA_EXTENSIONS", vsbExtensions);

        startActivityForResult(i,0);
    } 
 });
```

inside your Dialog's onClick event? That should cause it to run on the UI thread of the Activity.

Comment: A dialog is not an activity, so I can't use runOnUiThread either. Same reason I can't use startactivityforresult.

Comment: If your dialog is created inside your activity you should be able to use it. But since you say you can't, it sounds like you're using a separate class for your dialog, in which case, you should pass your Activity as a variable to your dialog class when constructing it and call runOnUiThread through that: IE. mActivity.runOnUiThread

Comment: The dialog is a dialogpreference, so I can't change the constructor. In any case, I ended up making a function in the dialogpreference that I called from the preference screen to pass in the activity for me to work with. It's not a very good workaround, but it gets the job done. I'm marking your answer as correct since I'm guessing it would work for other people.