# Android: onActivityResult null value

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

i am trying to fetch the value returned from the colorActivity in my mainActivitiy class but the value retrieve is null which i have no idea why. What can i do in order to get value from the colorAcvitity?

my codes are:
colorActivity

```
    public static final String CODE_KEY = "CODE";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_ecolor);


        circlenametextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.circlenametextview);


        String circlename = super.getIntent().getStringExtra("circlename");
          circlenametextview.setText(circlename);//get the circle name


savebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


               colorcode = colorEditText.getText().toString();
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                 resultIntent.putExtra(CODE_KEY, colorcode );

                   setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                   finish();
            }// onclick

        });
        }
```

mainActivity class

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1) { /

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Bundle buddle = data.getExtras();
                ccode = buddle.getString(colorActivity.CODE_KEY);

        }

        }
    }

    public static String getcolorcode() { // so that i can use it in my view class
        return ccode; 
    }
```

my view class:

```
      @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();


            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++) {


                    if (circles.get(i).contains(x, y)) {
                        circleID = i;

        Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(
                                            getContext());
                                    final EditText text = new EditText(getContext());

                                    builder.setTitle("Adding colors to circles").setMessage(
                                            "Proceed to Enter color");
                                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface di,
                                                        int i) {

                       Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),colorActivity.class);
                                                                                                                                                        intent.putExtra("circlename", circleNameList.get(circleID));


                    ((Activity) getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent,1);


                                                }

                                            });
                                    builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface di,
                                                        int i) {
                                                }

                                            });

                                    builder.create().show();
                                }
                            }, 3000);
break;

}
```

Comment: Are you using startActivityForResult to start your colorActivity from your mainActivity?

Comment: where are you declaring ccode variable? is a class field? Check that REQUESTcode and RESULTcode are the correct values.

Comment: @Damien R. i have added my view class where is contains the startActivityForResult.

Comment: @alwar cccode is the value i want to retrieve.

Comment: Are you sure that mainActivity is the class which has your "my view class", so getActivity() is getting the instance of mainActivity? or it is a different activity?

Comment: @Guillermo Merino yes, the getActivity() gets the mainActivity

Comment: I feel stupid asking that, but have you a "private String ccode" in your mainActivity class??

Comment: @alwar yes i did declare that

Answer (score 0):

You have startActivityforResult in myview class and you are expecting results back in main Activity Class. Add onActivityResult in your myview Class.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your

`startActivityFromResult()` from the UI Thread, so modify your view code adding this:

```
Activity activity = ((Activity) getContext());

activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, colorActivity.class);
        ((Activity) getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent, 1);                
    }
});
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037826/startactivityforresult-from-dialogpreference-non-activity)